# Using OpenStreetMap Localy in my React app

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-leaflet

I have a React Web application and I have been asked to make an offline map so after I did a lot of research and to find a map that match also the features that the design have I finally found react-leaflet is the best choice for using a map.

But after I finished the installation for the map and the tile layer was using HTTPS to draw the map depending on the lat, lang, and center.

I have been asked one more time to turn off the map into an offline map so I figured out a solution after a little bit of search: which is to select an area on the map from osm (Open Street Map) and download an XML file that contains node tags that are responsible for drawing the map after that I used an application to read that file which is (Maperitive).

I made and export for the map into small tiles layers. Finally, I added the tiles folder to my application as the attached image, and from the component, I used the path to navigate to that tiles folder to load the tiles. But the response is getting for me text/HTML and it should be image/png.

```
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";
import "styles/modules/vehicle/map.scss";

const Map: React.FC<any> = () => {

  const getIcon = (iconSize) => {
    return L.icon({
      iconUrl: require("assets/images/png/location.png"),
      iconSize,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="map">
      <MapContainer 
        center={[30.02161, 31.25146]}
        zoom={18}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
      >
        <TileLayer url='assets/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' />
        <Marker position={[30.02161, 31.25146]} icon={getIcon(60)}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

Comment: You should add the code to your question, not as images, as a [mcve], and also use paragraphs.

Comment: Also since you are requesting images (assets aka resources) from an external server, an API key may be needed to prevent over usage.

Comment: @Andy thank you, I just updated my question and added the map component code. I followed this approach because they need the map to be used without internet

Comment: @mardubbles I request the images from my local server after installing the tiles for a specific area to show it. I don't request an external server because they need it to be offline.

Comment: Well thats interesting that you can install that locally. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the Type in the network tab for the image is text/html and it should be png but I don't know why that happens.

Comment: event when I tried to change the url into this one https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png the type for the images was png so I was sure that is the problem but I didn't know so far how to fix it.